# How to change property of Class in an element of Observable Collection?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an `observable collection`, filled up with `Class properties`. I would like to change one of the properties in exactly 1 element when a `toggle button` is changed.

This is how the Collection looks like:

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> ceilingItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
ceilingItems.Add(new Item() { Category = language.GetString("top-mesh"), Name = "4. " + language.GetString("main-direction"), Value1 = list1, Unit1 = "mm", Value2 = list2, Unit2 = "cm", IsEditable = true });
ceilingItems.Add(new Item() { Category = "", Name = "3. " + language.GetString("side-direction"), Value1 = list1, Unit1 = "mm", Value2 = list2, Unit2 = "cm", IsEditable = false });
ceilingItems.Add(new Item() { Category = language.GetString("bottom-mesh"), Name = "2. " + language.GetString("side-direction"), Value1 = list1, Unit1="mm", Value2 = list2, Unit2 = "cm", IsEditable = false });
ceilingItems.Add(new Item() { Category = "", Name = "1. " + language.GetString("main-direction"), Value1 = list1, Unit1 = "mm", Value2 = list2, Unit2 = "cm", IsEditable = true });
ceilingItems.Add(new Item() { Category = language.GetString("lace"), Name = "", Value1 = list1, Unit1 = "mm", Value2 = list2, Unit2 = "cm", IsEditable = true });
ceilingItems.Add(new Item() { Category = language.GetString("spacer-iron"), Name = "", Value1 = list1, Unit1="mm", Value2 = list3, Unit2 = language.GetString("piece") + " / m2", IsEditable = true });
```

The `Item` class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Unit1 { get; set; }
    public List<double> Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Unit2 { get; set; }
    public bool IsEditable { get; set; }
}
```

I have a function where somehow (after button click) I would like to define, that the `IsEditable` of the `2. element of the collection` should change to `true`. I have no idea how to make it.

This is the function for the button:

```
private void ToggleButton1_IsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
            
}
```

Comment: How do you know which element (its index) you need to change? Is the button present next to every element in the collection?

Comment: The button is present where the default value of `IsEditable` is `false`. It is defined that those rows must be editable only when the button is not pushed (default is pushed).

Comment: If you know the index, `ceilingItems[index].IsEditable = true;` should work. In case any Binding to that property should be triggered, the Item class would have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and fire the PropertyChanged event in the IsEditable property setter.

Comment: If you didn't know the index but you know any other property of that object you want to edit that is UNIQUE then you might using LINQ (supposing that property is `Name`) `ceilingItems.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name.Equals("<name_to_match>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`

Comment: @Clemens could you post a short code for this, please? I am sure this is what I need, but I don't really know how to do this...

Comment: You mean the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation? There are plenty of examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwpf%5D+INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the item and set its property:

```
private void ToggleButton1_IsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = 1; //second element
    ceilingItems[index].IsEditable = true;          
}
```

If `IsEditable` is data bound, you should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the `Item` class to notify the UI of the change:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Unit1 { get; set; }
    public List<double> Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Unit2 { get; set; }

    private bool _isEditable;
    public bool IsEditable
    {
        get { return _isEditable; }
        set { _isEditable = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```